# Find $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{x\cos(4x)}{\sin^2(x)\cot^2(2x)}$

Tags: calculus

I need the help regarding the limit below:

Find $\underset{x\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{x\cos(4x)}{\sin^2(x)\cot^2(2x)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 \leq 
\left| \frac{x\cos(4x)}{\sin^2(x)\cot^2(2x)}\right|
&\leq&
\left| \frac{x}{\sin^2(x)\cot^2(2x)}\right|\\
&=&
\left| \frac{x}{\sin^2(x)\frac{cos^2(2x)}{\sin^2(2x)}}\right|\\
&=&
\left| \frac{x}{\sin^2(x)\frac{cos^2(2x)}{(2\sin x\cos x)^2}}\right|\\
&=&
\left| \frac{4x\cos^2 x}{\cos^2(2x)}\right|\\
&\leq&
\left| \frac{4x}{\cos^2(2x)}\right|\\
\end{eqnarray*}
And, since the numerator and denominator have limits independently and the limit of the denominator is not zero we get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{4x}{\cos^2(2x)}\right| = 
\frac{\lim_{x\to 0}\left|4x\right|}{\lim_{x\to 0}\left|\cos^2(2x)\right|}
=\frac{0}{1}=0
$$
Thus,
$$
0\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\left| \frac{x\cos(4x)}{\sin^2(x)\cot^2(2x)}\right|
\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{4x}{\cos^2(2x)}\right| =0
$$
So,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\cos(4x)}{\sin^2(x)\cot^2(2x)} =0
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) = L$ and  $\lim_\limits{x\to a} g(x) = M$ then $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = LM$

Can we break apart what is above into the product of limits that we know?

$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {x\cos 4x}{\sin^2x \cot^2 2x} = \lim_\limits{x\to 0} \frac {x\cos 4x\sin^2 2x}{\sin^2x \cos^2 2x} = \lim_\limits{x\to 0} x\left (\frac {\sin 2x}{\sin x}\right)^2 \frac {\cos 4x}{\cos^2 2x}$

You should be able to find the limits of each of those factors.